# How to limit the number of link in codeigniter pagination like google pagination?

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

I use pagination on codeigniter. when the data is less than 100, the pagination is still normal. the problem is when 1000 data, the number of pagination links is getting more and more long. What is the solution to be the same as **Google pagination** when the data is thousands, the number of links is still consistent?[image google pagination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdniV.png)

Comment: The number of “digit” links you would like before and after the selected page number: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html#customizing-the-pagination

Comment: then what if the data is more than 1000?